# How to move a part of my files to another ubuntu one account?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I want to give a part of my files to another ubuntu one account, in cause of change of responsibilities...
By now, the files are originally stored on my computer and shared to the other account. From now on, it should by vice-versa! The other account should be the source.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think that the easiest way is to copy the files from the share on your computer to some other folder and offer that folder as a share to the other Ubuntu One user.

Answer (score 0):

the Ubuntu One client is designed to only support a one account per OS user and the way to handles the configuration files, there's no clean way around this.

If you want to switch to a new account without going back to the other account (on Ubuntu):

1. Make sure all your files are in sync.
2. Backup the files syncing with Ubuntu One (Important in case you mess up any of the following steps)
3. Stop ubuntuone u1sdtool -q
4. Remove the Ubuntu One metadata: rm -rf  ~/.local/share/ubuntuone
5. Remove the openid token in the keyring: run seahorse and delete the key named "Ubuntu 
   One"
6. Restart Ubuntu One: u1sdtool -c
7. When prompted to login, login with the other account.

Ubuntu One will begin syncing the files to the other account. It may be a good idea to make sure the other account doesn't have the same files. Otherwise you could end up either with a lot of conflicts or in some cases, delete files (put them in the trash)